# Higcharts: How to remove the tooltip on the xAxis?

Tags: highcharts

I am having [this jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/5mcq1d3s/), where I need to hide the tooltip that shows on the xAxis. I want to keep the one that shows in the middle.

Here is some part of the related settings:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: data.slice(80, 110),
        type: 'area',
        threshold: null,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
    }],        
    yAxis: {        
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: 0,
            y: -5
        },
        opposite: false,
    },
```

This is the one I want to remove:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `tooltip.split` as a false should fix the issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Le8w0r63/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.split